# How to access a site with javascript for titanium mobile using the methods in an xmlrpc API?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I need help or hint on how to use xmlrpc service to connect to a site e.g. drupal with a titanium mobile client application and use the methods in the xmlrpc API.

Working with Remote Data

Interacting with remote web services and assets

- Make HTTP requests for remote data
- Interact with XML-RPC based web services
- Process XML data from web services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+Remote+Data